# Force win8 to freshen a mapped drive

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, mapped-drive

I have a NAS on my home network and it is mapped as drive K:. Sometimes the NAS is not ready as win starts up and the drive shows with red-"X" in File Explorer. If I click the drive with the X showing, it instantly displays the Folders, suggesting to me that it is now mapped but was not during the start up.

I have a very simple MP3 player I have written that believes the win red-X and not the actual status of the mapped drive, if that makes sense. If I click an MP3 file to play, it says the drive is not available. If I first click the drive in File Explorer, then the MP3 file, it works OK.

How can I add a "refresh" for that Mapped drive status in my MP3 player?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen someone suggested a scripted workarround for this - just try to access the path the drive is pointing to.
If your drive Z: points to \\server\share then this may work (for use in batch script):

```
pushd \\server\share
```

Programmatically you can try to use WNetAddConnection2 with arguments that mirror your mapped drive's parameters. Sample algorithm:

1. get connection status for the drive (WNetGetConnection)
2. if the status is ERROR_CONNECTION_UNAVAIL then use
   WNetAddConnection2 to reconnect

Take a look at [WNetRestoreConnectionW function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CommunityComments) in MSDN.
There user Chesare has published on 1/14/2011 sample reconnect code (in C/C++).

p.s. All this is not tested but may work for you - try it ;)

Comment: Thanks, but nothing short of clicking the Mapped drive in File Explorer seems to work.